# Binary String to List Python

Tags: python, list, binary

I've got a binary string like `'1100011101'`.
I would like to parse it into a list where each chunk of 1's or 0's is a separate value in the list.

Such as:
`'1100011101'` becomes `['11', '000', '111', '0', '1']`

Answer (score 3):

You can scrape a (minor) bit of performance out of this by using a regex instead of `groupby()` + `join()`. This just finds groups of `1` or `0`:

```
import re

s = '1100011101'
l = re.findall(r"0+|1+", s)
# ['11', '000', '111', '0', '1']
```

Timings:

```
s = '1100011101' * 1000

%timeit l = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]
# 1.16 ms ± 9.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit re.findall(r"0+|1+", s)
# 723 µs ± 5.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

binary = "1100011101"

result = ["".join(repeat) for _, repeat in groupby(binary)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['11', '000', '111', '0', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a space between the 01 and 10 transitions using .replace() and then split the resulting string:

```
'1100011101'.replace("01","0 1").replace("10","1 0").split()

['11', '000', '111', '0', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

with `groupby`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby as f
>>> x = str(1100011101)
>>> sol = [''.join(v) for k, v in f(x)]
>>> print(sol)
['11', '000', '111', '0', '1']
```

without using `groupby` and if you want more faster execution

```
def func(string):
    if not string:
        return []
    def get_data(string):
            if not string:
                return 
            count = 0
            target = string[0]
            for i in string:
                if i==target:
                    count+=1
                else:
                    yield target*count
                    count = 1
                    target = i
            if count>0:
                yield target*count
    return list(get_data(string))
        
    x = '1100011101'
    sol =func(x)
    print(sol)
```

output

```
['11', '000', '111', '0', '1']
```

Timings on my machine

```
 from itertools import groupby

s = '11000111010101' * 100000

%timeit l = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]
318 ms ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


import re

s = '11000111010101' * 100000

%timeit l = re.findall(r"0+|1+", s)
216 ms ± 2.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


def func(string):
    if not string:
        return []
    def get_data(string):
            if not string:
                return 
            count = 0
            target = string[0]
            for i in string:
                if i==target:
                    count+=1
                else:
                    yield target*count
                    count = 1
                    target = i
            if count>0:
                yield target*count
    return list(get_data(string))

s = '11000111010101' * 100000

%timeit func(s)
205 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
####################################################################

from itertools import groupby

s = '11000111010101' * 1000

%timeit l = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]
3.28 ms ± 178 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


import re

s = '11000111010101' * 1000

%timeit l = re.findall(r"0+|1+", s)
2.06 ms ± 57.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


def func(string):
    if not string:
        return []
    def get_data(string):
            if not string:
                return 
            count = 0
            target = string[0]
            for i in string:
                if i==target:
                    count+=1
                else:
                    yield target*count
                    count = 1
                    target = i
            if count>0:
                yield target*count
    return list(get_data(string))

s = '11000111010101' * 1000

%timeit func(s)
1.91 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```